# How to test dynamic classes with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a set of services and submodules as follows:

```
class Calculate::Document

   def self.build
     new 
   end

   def initialize
     @country_codes = [1,2,3]
   end

   def call(document)
     ...
     @document = document
     calculate_by_country
   end

   private

   def calculate_by_country
     #define by country
     location = (@country_codes.include? @document.country_code) ? @document.country_code : 'Generic'
     #Build dynamic class name
     klass = ('Calculate::Document::Countries::' + location.titleize + '::Base').constantize
     #call dynamic class
     @document = klass.build.call(@document)
    end
end

class Calculate::Document::Countries::Usa::Base

  def self.build
    new(
        ...
        )
  end

  def initialize(...)
    ....
  end

  def call(document)
    @document = document
    .....
    return @document
  end
end
```

And I'm testing the above with rspec as follows:

```
describe Calculate::Document do

  before do
    @service = Calculate::Document.build
    @document = FactoryGirl.build(:document, country_code: 'usa')
  end

  context "unit tests" do

    it "calls calculate_by_country" do
      calculate_by_country = instance_double("PayrollService::CalculatePayslip::Countries::Usa::Base", call: nil)
      @service.call(@document)
      expect(calculate_by_country).to have_received(:call).with(@document)
    end

  end
end
```

Basically I'm trying to test if the service calls the dynamically named submodule and that the submodule returns an object with so and so attributes. The code works but the test doesn't.

How do I test dynamically named classes with rspec?

Comment: It's not really any different to if the class names were hard coded. Are you trying to test that calculate_by_country was called or that calculate_by_country instantiates the right thing? Your spec says the former but your question seems to suggest the latter.

Comment: @FrederickCheung Both really. I need to test that 1) calculate_by_country was called and 2) calculate_by_country returns an object with the desired calculations.

Comment: @FrederickCheung The 2nd condition is passing, so I've left that out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `double` is not the object that is being instantiated in `call`, try:

```
expect_any_instance_of(PayrollService::CalculatePayslip::Countries::Usa::Base).to receive(:call).with(@document)
@service.call(@document)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. All specs passing without any issues.

Comment: Changed expect().to have_received to expect_any_instance_of().to receive and calling the service after the expect is all it took.

Comment: Hmm, I've retested it again with both ().to and ().to_not receive and both tests pass, so I think the expect is not being tested.

Comment: @Ryan.lay expectations do stack, so if you add 2 expectations in this order and the call happens only once then they will both pass

Comment: You're right. But in my case I've added a receive.once.and_return(...) and that was somehow causing the false positive. Removing that causes the test to work as expected. Thanks for the help =)